# Thin-tentacle alien enwrapping its victims

Tags: story-identification, horror

I saw it in the 90s. Could have been a 70s-90s sci-fi horror movie or an episode of a series.
The story played out on either a space ship or in some sort of a planet base.

I remember only the tentacles, not sure if the rest of the alien was depicted. However the tentacles were multiple, very fast moving, no thicker than 3/4 in or 2cm.
The victims were enveloped in them and the tentacles tightened on its victim like the rubber bands on a melon.
The protagonist(s) were shutting the doors to block it from moving from compartment to compartment.

It was memorable for the absolute dread it caused in me so I doubt it was one of those light hearted- slow paced sci-fi series from back in the day, but I might be wrong. It's been a while.

I looked through every single thread about tentacle aliens in here and could not find anything matching that description. I'd really want to rewatch that thing as it's been hunting me for over two decades.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: I'm reminded a bit of an episode of the 1970's cult sci-fi series SPACE:1999.  There was an episode called "Dragon's Domain", where a tentacled horror was discovered aboard an alien spacecraft.  The tentacles were quite a bit thicker than what you mentioned, however.  Here's a link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHMB9ox4uF4

Comment: I've checked out that episode, but its definitely not the one sadly

Answer (score 2):

It could be [Star crystal](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092006/)

> Set in 2032, as missions from Earth are being sent to explore Mars.
> After two groups of astronauts are mysteriously killed following the
> discovery of strange artefacts on the martian surface, the crew of the
> SC-37 go in to try and find out what happened. They soon learn what
> became of their predecessors when a bloodthirsty space monster begins
> lunching on members of the crew. Will any of them make it back to
> Earth alive?

Locking the doors:
[image]

[image]

Alien on the scanner:
[image]

Tentacles:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you describe what parts of Star Crystal are matches for the question? If possible [edit] them in.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Tentacles right on video, crew trying to lock part of the ship. Put that into answer?

Comment: Yes please do [edit] that in

Comment: @AncientSwordRage done

Comment: I was thnking more describing the contents of the video, but I guess screencaps also work

Answer (score 1):

The "Space: 1999" episode "Dragon's Domain had a many tentacled being on a space station.  It entangled it's victims and then spit them out after some form of consumption. One crew member is pursued by the creature, closing doors behind him to try to prevent it from reaching him.  It was a quite disturbing episode.

[image]